# Update a column based on column from another table

Tags: oracle

Why does my update statement say - "cannot insert null into gitb_auto_debit_upload.status". The second query returned a record where the column process_status was having 'P' as its value.

```
 Update gitb_auto_debit_upload a
              set status = (select nvl(process_status,'O') from gitb_daily_log b
               where b.interface_code      = 'PHP661OW'
                    and b. process_ref_no    = '4708'
                   and a.refno                           = b.external_ref_no
                   and a.recordno                   = b. seq_no
              ) ;




  select * from gitb_auto_debit_upload a, gitb_daily_log b  where b.interface_code      = 'PHP661OW'
                    and b. process_ref_no    = '4708'
                   and a.refno                           = b.external_ref_no
                   and a. recordno                   = b. seq_no
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message comes from a record in gitb_auto_debit_upload  for which the select (the one inside the update) statement returns no row.

Your update statement processes all records of gitb_auto_debit_upload.
Your select (the one you use to test the status value) statement only those records for which a record in gitb_daily_log exists.

You need to change the update statement to either only update those rows for whicht the select return a row or to place the NVL() around the select.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.